# Problems with {low_search_search:channel_field} tag

Tags: low-search

I have this form

```
{exp:low_search:form collection="test" secure="no" search_mode="any" loose_ends="yes" result_page="test/"}
    <fieldset>
        <h2>{low_search_search:region}</h2>
        <h2>{low_search_search_mode}</h2>

        <label for="region">Region:</label>
        <select class="span12" name="search:region" id="region">
            <option></option>
            {exp:channel:entries channel="regions" orderby="region_name" sort="asc"}
                <option value="{region_name}">{region_name}</option>
            {/exp:channel:entries}
        </select>

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Search</button>
    </fieldset>
{/exp:low_search:form}
```

I tried choosing a region and then submit it. This form submits it to itself.

But after submission, the content of the first h2 tag above(low_search_search:region) is empty while the second one(low_search_search_mode) is showing "any".

Why isn't "low_search_search:channel_field" working? Is there something wrong that I am doing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `query="{segment_2}"` to the Form tag, so it knows what has been submitted.

Comment: Yep, it solved the problem. Low Search support is awesome! Thanks a lot.